# How to define a memory aligned template pointer as a C++ class member? (intel/gcc)

Tags: c++, icc, auto-vectorization

I have a matrix class that has a pointer class member (data pointer to the class template variable) and I would like to declare it as a pointer to aligned memory just as a hint to intel compiler that it can use aligned access for auto-vectorized code. The short version of the code is as below:

```
template <class V>
class matrix{
public:

    typedef __declspec(align(64)) V VA;
    VA * data;
    

    int nrows, ncols;
}
```

When I check optimization report I see that access to data is not aligned unless I use __assume_aligned in the code block where I use matrix.data.

Please let me know if there is an alternative to let the intel/gcc compiler know that data field is an aligned pointer so that I don't have to use __assume_aligned everywhere there is an access to the pointer.

Answer (score -1):

This issue has been already resolved in the Intel community. Please refer the below link

https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-C-Compiler/How-to-define-a-memory-aligned-template-pointer-as-a-C-class/m-p/1287633#M38894

_mm_malloc assures gives a hint to the compiler to align the memory access. Alignment assures there is no peeled loop present that is what is happening in the second example.

Using only malloc makes the chances of a loop getting aligned lower. In this case, the loop is not aligned resulting in peeled loops.